# How to get the filtered index when chaining filtering and map methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

Lets say we have an array of objects that contains x amount entries.

E.G of an entry is

```
{
 name: 'someone',
 age: 22,
 modified: true
}
```

Now we want to filter the entries so that we can obtain all the entries that contain modified = true, by using the filter method. Once filtered we will then map the results to a div.

E.G:

```
return this.props.entries.filter((entry) => {
  return entry.modified === true;
}).map((displayedEntry, index) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{index + 1}</td>
      <td>displayedEntry.name</td>
    </tr>
  );
});
```

The problem is that the index that is displayed corresponds to the amount of entries that were filtered: If 4 items were modified our would be index = [0,1,2,3].

My question is how can we pass the index of the item within the original array rather then the index of the item within the mapped array.

So if items at index: 5,10 were modified I could pass these indexes when mapping the results?

I hope I explained this clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to mangle your original object, use a projection:

```
    return this.props.entries
    .map((entry, index) => {
        return {
            entry: entry,
            index: index
        };
    })
    .filter((proj) => {return proj.entry.modified === true;})
    .map(proj => {
        return (
            <tr>
              <td>{proj.index + 1}</td>
              <td>proj.entry.name</td>
            </tr>
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ugly, but you could do something like:

```
return this.props.entries.
  map((entry, index) => {
    entry.displayIndex = index;
    return entry;
  }).
  filter((entry) => {
    return entry.modified === true;
  }).
  map((displayedEntry, index) => {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{displayedEntry.displayIndex + 1}</td>
        <td>displayedEntry.name</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
```

Comment: This is what I had originally done, but wanted to avoid modifying the entries.